# Magento 2 - how to connect/use Mongo DB

Tags: magento2.3

I want to connect MongoDB to my magento 2.x website and store some custom entries in same.

So basically I will require connection details and how i can insert and update the records in mongo db. Please note my primary db will be mysql. Mongo DB will a additional DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magento 2. does not have any connector for connecting with **MongoDB**.

Magento only has **MySQL connector and  SQL(for only Commerce version)**.

If you want to  connect Magento with  Mongo then can try [**MongoDB PHP Driver**](https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/php/).